# Jerky animation with ui bootstrap and horizontal collapse

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Why is the horizontal collapse jerky? It starts to open normally, stops for a bit, and then opens completely. There are no margins, nor padding on the elements in this example

https://plnkr.co/edit/85K7YhCG0inVpcwAhyjC?p=preview

Edit: It runs smoother if I put a fixed width on the contents (Set ul to width 400px). Is this the only way?

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" ng-init="nc=true;">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="uib-collapse" uib-collapse="nc" horizontal>
              <ul class="">
                  <li ng-repeat="menu in fm.genericMenus" class="" >
                      <a class="" href="" ng-href="{{menu.Url}}" ng-bind="menu.Text"></a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>

          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="nc=!nc">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span>Click</span>
          </button>

          <a href="#" class="logo">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/bar/a/a6/Nintendo-Logo.svg" />
          </a>
      </div>
  </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
.logo img {
  width:100px;
}

ul {
  padding:0;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

a {
  font-size:8px;
}

.uib-collapse, button {
  float:right;
  height:50px;
}

button {
  margin:0 !important;
}

.collapsing {
  transition-duration:3s;
}
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fm = {
    genericMenus:[
        {Text:'CALENDAR'},
        {Text:'BUYING'},
        {Text:'SELLING'},
        {Text:'DEPARTMENTS'},
        {Text:'NEWS & VIEWS'}
      ]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug with the library. I'm getting the [same behavior](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) on the bootstrap demo page. Less noticeable because they have faster easing, but it's there. Your workaround seems like a good interim solution.

Comment: Some digging into the code has led me to the fact that it is animating the width from 0 to `scrollWidth` and that value is incorrect for the final width of the collapse. I've found it also does this for vertical collapse. It then on completing that transition sets width (or height) to `auto`, hence the jump. How did they ever think this was going to work?

Comment: This is known issue for UI-Bootstrap. They've updated their page with the following warning: When using the horizontal attribute with this directive, CSS can reflow as the collapse element goes from 0px to its desired end width, which can result in height changes. This can cause animations to not appear to run. The best way around this is to set a fixed height via CSS on the horizontal collapse element so that this situation does not occur, and so the animation can run as expected.